# openssl upgrade with in-house rpm leads to libcrypto.so.10 not found on CentOS 6.6 x64

Tags: linux, openssl, centos, rpm

I am on a fully updated CentOS 6.6 x64 box.

```
uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Feb 9 22:46:17 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It is running openssl 1.0.1e

```
rpm -qa | grep openssl
openssl-1.0.1e-42.el6_7.4.x86_64
```

We are making a new rpm with openssl 1.0.2f and upgrading to that version. The rpm install completes but there are two lines output during upgrade.

```
/sbin/ldconfig: /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.2 is not symbolic link
/sbin/ldconfig: /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.2 is not symbolic link
```

After the rpm upgrade, packages are not able to use the new so's because of missing libcrypto.so.10 and libssl.so.10.

These links are not created by the rpm. But here is the kicker - even if I manually create libcrypto.so.10 symlink to the new so in /usr/lib64, the applications do not work.

```
# ssh root@localhost
ssh: /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10: version 'libcrypto.so.10' not found (required by ssh)
```

ldd however is able to find the so

```
/usr/bin/ssh: /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10: version `libcrypto.so.10' not found (required by /usr/bin/ssh)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffc1da0000)
    libfipscheck.so.1 => /lib64/libfipscheck.so.1 (0x00007fdf17567000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007fdf17348000)
    libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007fdf16e9b000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fdf16c98000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007fdf16a82000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007fdf16868000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007fdf16631000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fdf16417000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007fdf161d2000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007fdf15eeb000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007fdf15cbf000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007fdf15aba000)
    libnss3.so => /usr/lib64/libnss3.so (0x00007fdf1577b000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fdf153e7000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fdf151e2000)
    libplc4.so => /lib64/libplc4.so (0x00007fdf14fdd000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fdf179ea000)
    libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007fdf14dda000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007fdf14bce000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007fdf149cb000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fdf147ae000)
    libnssutil3.so => /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so (0x00007fdf14581000)
    libplds4.so => /lib64/libplds4.so (0x00007fdf1437d000)
    libnspr4.so => /lib64/libnspr4.so (0x00007fdf1413f000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007fdf13f36000)
```

Why are the applications not able to use the new so and how can I fix this manually now and eventually in the rpm ?

Comment: If the soname/version changed then the libraries aren't binary compatible and things built to use 1.0.1 will not work with 1.0.2. You **should not** replace core system libraries like this. It will generally not work and will generally cause problems like you are seeing. If you want to install a new version of a core library *in addition* that's something you can do but under an alternate prefix and only things you build against it will then use it.

Comment: @Etan - my intention was to upgrade just this package for a specific need (without touching other packages). Are you saying the error message means there is an export that was in use in 1.0.1e that is missing in 1.0.2f or something else ? What is binary compatibility ?

Comment: You replaced the *system* openssl package. The one that **every** other default openssl-using package was built against. That's a bad idea. Different versions of the same library are *not* drop-in replaceable for one another. That's why they have version numbers. If you need a newer version of openssl for a specific need then you get to install it separately and use it for just that one need (without messing with the system itself).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: @jww - This is not a Dev Ops question, although your site might be calling it that. I am not in Dev Ops and rpm questions are not necessarily Dev Ops although some questions might be Dev Ops. Please note that I am building the rpm and I have run time issues that perhaps a developer that knows how the loader works can answer.

Comment: @Etan yes I want to replace system openssl package for a validation program requirement. Do you know who is giving this message and why ? All binaries needed by all packages have been satisfied since otherwise the rpm would not install.

Comment: Your problem isn't with the openssl package's *dependencies* your problem is with every package that depends on openssl. Unless you rebuilt just about every package on the system that's not going to have been sorted out correctly (or you lied in your RPM to satisfy the file requirements). This really just isn't a good (or at all supported) idea. Don't do it.

Comment: @Etan what you are saying sounds empirically true but does not explain why this happens ? Which component does what to stop the loading ? Forget about the other packages for a second. What is specifically happening here ? Is it an elf header field that the application is looking for ? What is going on and why ?

Comment: That is presumably a so version symbol in the binary. Try `objdump -x` on `/usr/bin/ssh` perhaps? And the same on your built `libcrypto.so.10` (or whatever). Did the new version of openssl really build a `libcrypto.so.10` or did you have to rename/symlink that file?